# Primefaces calendar allows invalid date

Tags: date, calendar, primefaces

I am using primefaces calendar but i am allowed to enter invalid date.For e.g. enter date as 32-06-2012 in the input box for date field and save the record. It is saving the date as is saving the date as 02-07-2012. Same behavior can be observed in showcase of primefaces also.

Reference : http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/calendarBasic.jsf

Here is my code

```
<p:calendar id="copyStartDateCalendar" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"

         mode="popup" showOn="button" size='8' >

                <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/yyyy" />

</p:calendar>
```

What should be done as there seems to be some error with the component itself.

Thanks & Regards

Tarun Madaan

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problems with the primefaces calendar.

For one it accepts dates with two digits though a pattern of `pattern="dd.MM.yyyy"` is set. Like `20.06.12` will be shown in the calendar popup as `20.06.2012` misleading the user to think the date was correctly recognized. But the year 12 is actually set.

Anyways, I ended up setting a `<f:validator>` inside the `<p:calendar>` like this:

```
<p:calendar value="#{abschnittDView.bogen.pruefungsDatum}
    mode="popup" locale="de" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" required="true"
    requiredMessage="Please provide a date."
    converterMessage="Date is invalid.">

    <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" 
        timeZone="Europe/Berlin" locale="de" />

    <f:validator validatorId="de.common.DateValidator" />

</p:calendar>
```

Then doing some validation on the given date:

```
@FacesValidator(DateValidator.VALIDATOR_ID)
public class DateValidator implements Validator {

    public static final String VALIDATOR_ID = "de.common.DateValidator";

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, 
        Object value) throws ValidatorException {

        Date inputDate = (Date) value;
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(inputDate);
        if (cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) < 1000) {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Please provide a date with 4 digits for the year", null));
        }
    }
```

I know this prevents dates below 1000 but in my case it is absolutely clear that the date can not be lower then 2000.

So the suggestion is: Use a `Validator` to make sure the dates are correct. 
I know it is not the perfect solution but maybe a possible workaround.

Otherwise, try to ask for this on the primefaces forum.

Comment: Would this work with the PrimeFaces problems such as converting invalid dates such as '30/02/2012' to '2/6/2014' because by the time it gets to the back end it has already been converted to a valid date?

Comment: Further details of above point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763717/primefaces-calendar-accepts-invalid-dates-as-input

Comment: His issue is that 2 digits of a 'day'/'month' rolls over and maps it to a proper month in the future/past - this is due to SimpleDateformat having leniency true, using the converter should solve this. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `readonly="true"` at such case you don't need to use any server side validators. This option will allow to the end user only to pick up the date from calendar panel.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern and f:convertDateTime have different patterns?

It's likely not able to figure out what you want in your converter as entering in data as 
dd/mm/yyyy - then your converter tries to convert that to MM/yyyy.

The issue you describe is because leniency is set to true in the simple date formatter in side primfaces (its a default action). To force is you then use your convertDatetime which should fix it but your patterns may not match it seems.

However, if using a verison of PF < 4 you'll then get java script issues as there is a bug in p:calendar converters returning null objects after validation - you can do some manual fixes for this inside the PF code after rebuilding it.