# MM/dd/yyyy format in p:calendar

Tags: jsf, primefaces, calendar

In reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13763717/1391249) question,
it still accepts `8/1/201987` as a date, where in `201987` is not in `yyyy` format.

How to ensure `yyyy` format? Do I need to validate it in the bean?

I have used the code below :

```
<p:calendar ...>
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
</p:calendar>
```

But as it uses `SimpleDateFormat`, if you give `yyyy` it accepts any number of digits.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Avoid the `<f:convertDateTime>` mess and simply use the `pattern` attribute associated with `<p:calendar>`. Use, if necessary, a custom converter of your own (probably using other than the poorly-implemented `java.util.Date` API).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restrict the user input by adding attributes *mask="true"* and *maxlength=10*

Answer (score 1):

Try mask for p:calender like mask="99/99/9999", it's works fine for me

```
<p:calendar value="8/1/201989" mask="99/99/9999">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
</p:calendar>
```

Comment: The problem with this masking is that it still considers 55/55/5555 as a valid date. Is there any way by which we can prevent user from entering month greater then 12 and days greater then 31?